# test for subclass with getType in conditional in java

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements

I have to find out if a method return type is a subclass of a certain base class. So far I can find no built in way to do this, I can only find a way to test for an exact class match. I can also do this using annotations, but the idea is that I don't want to have to add extra code if I happen to add a new subclass. I thought of testing against all possible subclasses, or creating an untyped object and testing the instance of it using "instanceof", but nothing seems ideal. Ideally:

```
if (m.getReturnType() Extends Superclass.class)
```

but there is no "extends" with functionality similar to "instanceof" with actual instances. Is there a conditional operator that I don't know about? Thank you in advance for any ideas.

This is actually for an android project, so I might not be able to implement all possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%3C%3F%3E%29).

When using it with just regular Java,

```
   System.out.println(List.class.isAssignableFrom(LinkedList.class));
```

Prints out `true`. As does:

```
  System.out.println(Queue.class.isAssignableFrom(LinkedList.class));
```

Because LinkedList can be treated as both a List and a Queue. However,

```
   System.out.println(ArrayList.class.isAssignableFrom(LinkedList.class));
```

Prints `false`, since LinkedList **cannot** be treated like an ArrayList.

Comment: That did it. Not sure how I missed that function :)

Comment: I only just found it recently. Not exactly an obvious name :-)